# How can I find all of my wolves?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The previous solution [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194739/how-can-i-find-my-pet-wolves-that-i-told-to-sit), no longer is accurate for the Java version of Minecraft. I am running the command on a server and trying to use my [UUID](https://mcuuid.net/).

Unfortunately when I try the solution that was posted in that 2014 question:

```
/scoreboard objectives add mine dummy
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Wolf] mine 1 {Sitting:1}
/tp @e[score_mine_min=1] @p
```

And switch {Sitting:1} with OwnerUUID="UUID", I get the error "Invalid or unkown entity type 'minecraft'.

Is there a way to teleport all the wolves I own?

Comment: "The current answer is outdated so I'm going to ask an identical question" is not how Stack Exchange works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only teleport wolves which are rendered, maybe this would cause some problems, but in general, this should work:

```
/tp @e[type=minecraft:wolf,nbt={OwnerUUID:'your uuid'}] @s
```

This will teleport all wolves which the game can find to the executing entity, in your case if you execute this in the chat, to you.
Of course, the game can only find rendered wolves.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. Is it /tp @e[type=minecraft:wolf,nbt={OwnerUUID:'12345'}] @s or /tp @e[type=minecraft:wolf,nbt={OwnerUUID:123456}] @s

Comment: /tp @e[type=wolf,nbt={OwnerUUID:"copy-UUID-here"}] PlayerName worked for me. Unless that was what @s stood for.

Answer (score 0):

You're using 1.12 syntax. It's now `/scoreboard players set @e[type=wolf,nbt={Sitting=1}] mine 1` and `/tp @e[scores={mine=1..}]`. More information on the corresponding wiki pages. Most commands changed a lot in 1.13.